# Cross correlation using FPGAs

Tags: fpga

I have the requirement of performing continuous cross correlation on an incoming signal with a reference signal that is 6000 coefficients large using an Intel FPGA at a data rate of 66 MSPS. One approach to implement the cross correlation is using Intel FIR filter IP. However, the resources utilization using the FIR filter IP is too high (more than 500 DSP blocks) due to the reference signal large number of coefficients (6000). Do you happen to know a better and more efficient (in terms resources utilization) approach for implementing cross correlation using FPGAs?

Comment: If there is a chance to implement 6000 x 66M = 396 billion mult-add operations per second mainly depends on the size of your value - how many bits do your values and coefficients have?

Comment: Any chance of [using an FFT](http://www.phys.uri.edu/nigh/NumRec/bookfpdf/f13-2.pdf)?

Comment: Do you need the whole correlation? If you can make do with not calculating every tau you may consider a multi-tau correlation which can save a significant amount of resources.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments . The answers to the comments are as follows: 1) The width of the incoming data and the coefficients are 12 bits. 2) FFT is considered as an option. 3) My signal processing team prefers that I perform the entire correlation.

Comment: Please provide me with references for multi-tau correlation.

Comment: @user345919 [This site](https://lsinstruments.ch/en/theory/digital-correlator-technology/multi-tau-correlator) might give you an idea on how it works. There are also two papers referenced at the bottom that may be of help. One of them shows an implementation of a multi-tau correlator on FPGA, though there are many other implementations out there and even some with easily accessible open-source code. There are also some software implementations that may give you a better idea on how multi-tau works. There are a ton more papers out there on multi-tau if you google.

Comment: Thanks Christopher.